# How to alert a value in jQuery using if condition

Tags: jquery

I have an `if` condition in jQuery,

```
if (($("input[value=Add]").prop("disabled") == true) || ($("input[value=Modify]").prop("disabled") == true) || ($("input[value=Delete]").prop("disabled") == true))
```

I need to alert the value which will show me true or false depending on the above `if` condition. Can someone help me with the alert statement?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What part of adding an alert are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Do you mean you want to fire an alert before this line telling you want the value of the resulting boolean is?

Comment: Only one can be true or several?

Comment: j08691- I have difficulty with adding an alert for the boolean value. If the value is true for the if condition it should display true or else false in the alert

Comment: Ziv Weissman- Several can be true or false depending on the if condition

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want the value of the first `input` element that was disabled.

```
var inputs = [ $("input[value=Add]")[0], 
               $("input[value=Modify]")[0], 
               $("input[value=Delete]")[0] ], // put the relevant input (raw DOM element) in an array
    disabled = inputs.filter(input => input.disabled); // filter the disabled ones only

if (disabled.length) alert(disabled[0].value); // if a disabled exist alert the first ones value
```

---

If, on the other hand, only one can be disabled then you can do it directly

```
var disabled = $("input[value=Add],input[value=Modify],input[value=Delete]").filter(':disabled');

if (disabled.length) alert(disabled.val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try to use Javascripts alert() function after the if condition

```
if (($("input[value=Add]").prop("disabled") == true) ||
($("input[value=Modify]").prop("disabled") == true) || ($("input[value=Delete]").prop("disabled") == true)){
alert("Your alert text");
}
```